# What is the UN "Global Code"?

Tags: classification, un

The UN on the [*"Standard country or area codes for statistical use (M49)"*](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/overview/) makes mention of "Global Code". It's `001` for every entry in the table. The "Global Name" is likewise "World". What is the Global Code, and is it defined for anything that is not `001`? By extension is there a "Global Code" for anything that is not "World"?

Answer (score 2):

The UN Global Code `001` and the Global Name `World` are being used as delimiters for a taxonomy; it does seem very redundant, as well as implied, however there probably is a good reason for it.
Toggling the [Geographic Regions](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/#geo-regions) closed is what made this makes sense to me:

Geographic Regions Toggled Open:
[image: Geographic Regions Toggled Open]

Geographic Regions Toggled Closed:
[image: Geographic Regions Toggled Closed]